# Methods to compress rows of dataset

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am working with large datasets on Spark and then converting to Pandas. I have a file that only has 2 or 3 features but has many rows. I need to retain as much information as possible but when I convert to Pandas the number of rows causes memory issues.

I am aware of methods to reduce the number of features. Are there any techniques that can compress the records?

An idea I had was to split the features into small ranges and then count the number of records in each range.
For instance: (0.01<x<0.02 , count = 12) and then repeat this for all combination of ranges

Comment: What do you need to convert to pandas for that the pandas on spark api can't do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate your rows to reduce the size of a dataset.

If you have numerical values, you can use binning which consists of assigning ranges of values to categories.
For instance, with this Spark SQL expression you can create the `age_group` column from the numerical column `age`.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("age_group", F.expr("CASE WHEN age <= 18 THEN '18-' "+\
                                                   "WHEN age < 30 THEN '18-30' "+\
                                                   "WHEN age < 40 THEN '30-40' "+\
                                                   "WHEN age < 50 THEN '40-50' "+\
                                                   " ELSE '50+' END"))
```

You could also use the Bucketizer class from Spark which you can read about here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.Bucketizer.html

Once you have categorised your feature, you can group your data (in my example by `age_group`) and select, for instance, the average of the other features for each categories.

```
df.groupBy("age_group").agg(F.avg("feature_2"),F.avg("feature_3"))
```

You would end up with a table with less rows but you would also lose informations. So I would suggest either to stay in Spark and avoid using Pandas, or think carefully on how you aggregate your data.

Hope this help !